# Weird Ubuntu Operation, works at home all plugged into a bunch of stuff, but on road it kept crashing

Tags: laptop, 19.04, msi

Using Ubuntu 19.04 I have a weird issue:

I have my laptop at home plugged into a usb hub with like 10 different devices.  As well I plug in external speakers into the sound port, and finally I use both wireless and ground connections for networking.
Oh yes, I also plug in a Dell monitor.

Where the the trouble started was when I took my laptop on the road this weekend.  I traveled out of town and when I ran the laptop with no devices attached against a hotel wireless network I would launch applications and the system would constantly crash.

I did get some work done with Chrome working but sometimes it would just go totally unresponsive.  I then thought it was working great and solid at home, why is it jacked on the road.  So I just brought my laptop back in my house and plugged everything in and I can't make the thing crash.  What was the difference on the road running in mobile mode?

To regain stability on the road I did revert back to an older kernel but when I did that I lost my networking so working with Ubuntu on the road was a complete disaster.  But now at home it is working great again.

Comment: Was on the road using battery and at home plug into power?  Can you list types of devices plug into usb?  Also which Ubuntu version.

Comment: I have made progress in figuring this all out.  I was running the nouveau open source driver for my laptop so that I could output on my hdmi to a second monitor.  This driver appears to jack everything when not on second monitor.  When I run it just on the laptop the laptop is unstable.  I know this because I installed the nvidia driver that is proprietary and the laptop is stable like on the road.  Now the problem I have is getting my second monitor to work with the nvidia driver.

Comment: It should be possible to switch drivers in additional drivers, if you can't find a solution.  Think it would be a good idea to ask new question with your last line, to get better help.

Comment: So yes, you are right, I actually installed the nvidia properietary drivers and now the laptop is solid as a rock.  I did everything to it and I can't make it crash now.  I had bad luck with the nouvea open source drivers.  They do allow me to use my second monitor but when running in just laptop mode, the computer became very unstable.  Now I am trying to figure out how to get a second monitor to work with the nvidia drivers.  Linux is still not near as clean as windows on working on all hardware.  I have had great luck with Linux in virtualization but it is very painful on actual hardware.

Comment: @user68186 I admire your check mark, but they actually have to click the grey check mark and then it turns green...

Comment: Everything is now worked out.  Only 4 days of effort to stabilize Ubuntu.  I worked with an Nvidia engineer to install and configure the nvidia drivers correctly.  As well I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.10 and all is well, the system is rock solid now with the correct drivers.

Comment: Consider writing your own answer based on your comments in the space **Your Answer**. Then accept your answer as correct by clicking on the grey check mark  and turning it into the green check mark ✅ next to your answer after the mandatory waiting period. This will help others. Note: there is no waiting period to write your answer. The waiting period is just form marking your answer correct.